# class name using reflection in a VS2010 macro

Tags: .net, reflection, .net-3.5

I have a VS2010 macro that inserts bolierplate header text at top of each class. Running the macro inserts module name, developer, description, etc. as expected.

Instead of typing the module name, i would like to insert the name into the text. How do I get the class (or form name) name when I run the macro in the selected code page?

I have looked at reflection, but not sure how to get the form/class name my cursor is on for the macro execution

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you need all this crap like developer, module name, etc?

Comment: I don't know if reflection will work for you since there can technically be more than one class definition in a file (including nested or private classes). So if you found a way to say "the class defined in this file", you could get more than one result.

Comment: Dim projectItem As ProjectItem
        projectItem = DTE.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem
        Dim cName As String = projectItem.Name.ToString

Comment: sorry about that. it is needed by corporate rules, not mine and as you stated reflection doesn't work, but using the macro dte does.